# Commons Collections Vulnerability in cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

There is a well-known security vulnerability in apache commons-collection 3.2.1 (see https://www.kb.cert.org/vuls/id/576313 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COLLECTIONS-580).  This is fixed/mitigated in commons-collections 3.2.2.

All current versions of cassandra (including 4.0beta4) pull in commons-collections 3.2.1 via apache-rat 0.10. Is it possible to upgrade apache-rat to version 0.12 in order to pull in the latest version of commons-collections?
See https://github.com/apache/creadur-rat/commit/2380409fbcd02b418eceacfdc1e486bdbbca9632.  I made the below change in 3.0.24 src and recompiled without errors.

```
diff --git a/cassandra/cassandra-3.0-src/build.xml b/cassandra/cassandra-3.0-src/build.xml
index 73c9889d81..ed236443d4 100644
--- a/cassandra/cassandra-3.0-src/build.xml
+++ b/cassandra/cassandra-3.0-src/build.xml
@@ -402,3 +402,3 @@
           <dependency groupId="org.reflections" artifactId="reflections" version="0.9.12" />
-          <dependency groupId="org.apache.rat" artifactId="apache-rat" version="0.10">
+          <dependency groupId="org.apache.rat" artifactId="apache-rat" version="0.12">
              <exclusion groupId="commons-lang" artifactId="commons-lang"/>
@@ -1605,3 +1605,3 @@
     <artifact:dependencies pathId="rat.classpath">
-      <dependency groupId="org.apache.rat" artifactId="apache-rat-tasks" version="0.6" />
+      <dependency groupId="org.apache.rat" artifactId="apache-rat-tasks" version="0.12" />
       <remoteRepository refid="central"/>
```

Comment: it's better to report such things to the Cassandra dev mailing list, or open Jira issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA

Comment: Done.  Created a jira ticket for Cassandra here: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-16528.

The bug got a response so I'm posting the response here -> basically you can not include the libraries which are pulling in apache-rat when actually running cassandra.